# What native windows API or .NET classes uses the "Language Bar"?

Tags: .net, system-tray, trayicon

Disclaimer: *I'm a Java developer, this is an exercise for learning to code (what I think it's a) simple windows programs in .NET*

I was wondering the other day, what sort of calls (API or .NET classes) uses the windows "Language Bar" to change the language keyboard depending on the current window in use?

Let's say I want to code a small program that sits in the taskbar and read the name of the window that is in use (when my program is in the background), what are the basic steps to achieve this?

For the tray part, I guess it depends on the Windows I'm using, I stumple upon: [Deskbands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx#deskbands), TaskBar Thumbnails, The [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class, etc.
But the interesting part (for me at least) is how to get the name of the current window in use...

Any guidance or suggestion on the subject for my little experiment is more than welcome.

Comment: Too vague, review the MSDN article for the InputLanguage class.

Comment: Hi Hans Passant, thanks for the comment I'll edit the question to be more specific. I just read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage_methods.aspx (I'm not sure if that was the article you where talking about) I'm not trying to add a language to the language bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [RegisterShellHookWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The accepted answer in this question
[System Wide Shell Hook from .NET using Unmanaged DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596363/system-wide-shell-hook-from-net-using-unmanaged-dll)
has sample codes.